# How can I include a variable inside a callback function?

Tags: php, count, callback, scope, array-reduce

I'm trying to get counts of array values greater than `n`.

I'm using `array_reduce()` like so:

```
$arr = range(1,10);
echo array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b) { return ($b > 5) ? ++$a : $a; });
```

This prints the number of elements in the array greater than the hard-coded `5` just fine.

But how can I make `5` a variable like `$n`?

I've tried introducing a third argument like this:

```
array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b, $n) { return ($b > $n) ? ++$a : $a; });
//                                    ^                  ^
```

And even

```
array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b, $n) { return ($b > $n) ? ++$a : $a; }, $n);
//                                    ^                  ^                   ^
```

None of these work. Can you tell me how I can include a variable here?

Comment: For a broader view of the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/476

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The syntax to *capture parent values* can be found in the [`function .. use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) documentation under "Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope".

> .. Inheriting variables from the parent scope [requires the 'use' form and] is *not* the same as using global variables .. The parent scope of a closure is the function in which the closure was declared (not necessarily the function it was called from).

Converting the original code, with the assistance of `use`, is then:

```
$n = 5;
array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($n) {
    return ($b > $n) ? ++$a : $a;
});
```

Where `$n` is "used" from the outer lexical scope.

NOTE: In the above example, a *copy* of the value is supplied and the variable itself is not bound. See the documentation about using a reference-to-a-variable (eg. `&$n`) to be able and re-assign to variables in the parent context.